# RMI: Proper synchronization when Server is accessed by multiple clients

Tags: java, rmi

I started working with Java RMI a couple of days ago. I am wondering if the following example is properly synchronized.

Consider the following Server class which provides resource strings to clients. It shall never provide the same resource twice, therefor it stores the provided strings in a list. This is the ServerEngine class:

```
package dummy;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ServerEngine implements Server {
    private final String s1 = "Resource Object 1";
    private final String s2 = "Resource Object 2";
    private final LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    private final int timer = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String name = "server";
            ServerEngine engine = new ServerEngine();
            Server stub = (Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("ServerEngine bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ServerEngine exception:");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getResource() throws RemoteException {
        Object lock = new Object();

        if ( ! list.contains(s1)) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                // wait to ensure concurrency
                try {
                    lock.wait(timer);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
            list.add(s1);
            return s1;
        }

        if ( ! list.contains(s2)) {
            list.add(s2);
            return s2;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The Server interface:

```
package dummy;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Server extends Remote {
    public String getResource(boolean synced) throws RemoteException;
}
```

and the Client:

```
package dummy;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String name = "server";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            Server server = (Server) registry.lookup(name);

            boolean sync = args.length > 0;
            String s = server.getResource(sync);
            System.out.println("Resource: " + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception:");
        }
}

}
```

The ServerEngine is implemented in such a way that it will cause a concurrency issue. If two clients are started from two different VMs within five seconds then they both will get the same String returned.

From what I have researched so far, this is my approach to solve the issue:

```
package dummy;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ServerEngine implements Server {
    private final String s1 = "Resource Object 1";
    private final String s2 = "Resource Object 2";
    private final LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    private final int timer = 5000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String name = "server";
            ServerEngine engine = new ServerEngine();
            Server stub = (Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("ServerEngine bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ServerEngine exception:");
        }
    }

    private synchronized String localGetResource() {
        Object lock = new Object();

        if ( ! list.contains(s1)) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                // wait to ensure concurrency
                try {
                    lock.wait(timer);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
            list.add(s1);
            return s1;
        }

        if ( ! list.contains(s2)) {
            list.add(s2);
            return s2;
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public String getResource() throws RemoteException {
        return localGetResource();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if this is a feasible solution. Are there any caveats? Do I actually need a second function or could I synchronize getResource() directly?

Comment: Creating lock object inside a method and synchronizing on it does not make a sense. Each thread will lock on different lock object and that is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your synchronization is broken on several levels:

- You're not supposed to `wait()` on something unless you expect some other thread to `notify()` you.
- You're implementing only half of [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which translates to "no locking", as the same value may end up in the list several times.
- You should have a look at proper thread-safe collection implementations under `java.util.concurrent`, rather than doing this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your locally create lock object is useless, as tsolakp noted, every method call creates its own instance.
Create the object as a field in order to use it's monitor for sychronization.

If you declare a method as synchronized you've use implicitly the monitor of the instance the method is invoked on. It makes no sense to mix these two approaches.

If you want to synchronize the access to your list use the according object's monitor for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if the following example is properly synchronized.

It isn't synchronized at all. It uses a lock, but not correctly, so it isn't *sequentialized* either.

```
public String getResource() throws RemoteException {
    Object lock = new Object();

    if ( ! list.contains(s1)) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // wait to ensure concurrency
            try {
                lock.wait(timer);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        list.add(s1);
        return s1;
    }

    if ( ! list.contains(s2)) {
        list.add(s2);
        return s2;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You don't need all this, and you certainly don't need the `wait()`. This code will never actually lock the list effectively, because every invocation gets its own lock object.

Throw it all away and just synchronize the method:

```
public synchronized String getResource() throws RemoteException {

    if ( ! list.contains(s1)) {
        list.add(s1);
        return s1;
    }

    if ( ! list.contains(s2)) {
        list.add(s2);
        return s2;
    }
    return null;
}
```